# How to "re-propose" someone's abandoned Sandbox draft?

Tags: support, sandbox

I'm looking at an [older draft](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/721/104693) in the Sandbox that appears to be abandoned by the original poster. I'd like to bring attention to it, and potentially "re-propose" it as a draft that I'd then post once ready. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You could just edit the answer so that it goes to the top of the "Active" list in the sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just ask in our main chat room, [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). You only need 20 reputation anywhere on the network to chat, which you have. We are working on a better system to review older sandbox posts.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (which granted, is poorly phrased). The linked Sandbox answer *isn't* one of OP's proposals. Rather, its a proposal by someone else, and the OP is asking how to "repropose" it as a draft

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing My bad. I didn't click on the proposal itself actually, I also missed the title so I thought it was just about bringing attention to something.